# Para onde vão os dados de formulários HTML?

Tags: html

Em sites com cadastro, como o Facebook, para onde vão os dados quando você completa o cadastro?

E quando você loga no site, ele reconhece se você tem um conta ou não tem?

Answer (score 3):

Em termos gerais, acontece o seguinte:

1. O formulário é enviado para o servidor, no endereço indicado no atributo `action` do [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).
2. Um programa recebe os dados no ambiente do servidor – em PHP, C#, Java, Python, Ruby, enfim, pode ser praticamente qualquer linguagem.
3. O programa decide o que fazer com esses dados. Geralmente salvar em um banco de dados (por exemplo, num novo cadastro), ou comparar com dados já existentes no banco (por exemplo, num procedimento de login).

Answer (score 1):

Quando você se cadastra na [rede social](http://www.infoescola.com/sociedade/redes-sociais-2/) Facebook, os dados do formulário são enviados para vários [servidores](http://www.dell.com/learn/br/pt/brbsdt1/sb360/what-is-a-server) da empresa, fazendo então a persistência dos dados de usuários e de empresas.

Quando você loga no site, tem todo um sistema que utiliza diversas [linguagens de programação](http://www.infoescola.com/informatica/o-que-sao-linguagens-de-programacao/) (Python, JavaScript, Ruby, PHP, C#, Java, etc.) para validação dos dados digitados nos campos. Tem um carinha chamado [Banco de Dados](http://www.dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/o-que-e-um-banco-de-dados/) que são armazenados dados de todos usuários. Assim, quando você digita suas informações, é verificado se você já existe dentro desta base de dados.

Dê uma lida aqui [nesse artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Meu_primeiro_formulario_HTML) no qual irá te ensinar como desenvolver seu primeiro formulário em HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Os dados do formulário são enviados para um computador que normalmente chamamos de "servidor".

Dentro desse servidor é feito o processamentos dos dados. no caso de um cadastro, os dados são salvos num banco de dados (MySQL, Postgre, Oracle, MSSQL Server, dentre outros).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso de login, o mesmo processo é realizado com a diferença de que no servidor os dados enviados serão usados para comparar com dados existentes. Se existir e combinar com a senha informada, a autenticação é liberada. Caso contrário, é negada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]